Iceberg metadata access in Snowflake
Is there a way to access the metadata JSON files / metadata_log_entries file in Snowflake for externally mounted iceberg tables?
Trying to understand if those can be accessed and used for a UDF that can give the different timestamps - external users can use to time travel
Trying to read iceberg_table_name.metadata_log_entries in Snowflake

where are the original files store? they should be in an S3 or something similar?

@LucasM.Uriarte the original files are stored in Azure blob along with the metadata files
